# Flask-Admin custom action with unselected

Tags: python-3.x, flask-admin

Can we use `@action` decorator to work with unselected element?

When we use

```
@action
def action_custom(self, ids):
```

`ids` = selected element on page, but can we get unselected element here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack action.js in Flask-Admin and change the submit form to include the unchecked rows as hidden values and then you can pickup these values in your python @action method using the submitted form's getlist method.

At line 21 in [action.js](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/static/admin/js/actions.js) we have :

```
$('input.action-checkbox', form).remove();
$('input.action-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    form.append($(this).clone());
});

form.submit();
```

Change this so the unchecked rows are included with the form. Note the use of the `:not(:checked)` in the jQuery selector and the values are saved to hidden inputs named `'notrowid'`:

```
$('input.action-checkbox', form).remove();

$('input.action-checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function(i, v) {
    form.append($('<input>').attr({'type':'hidden', 'name':'notrowid', 'value': v.value}));
});

$('input.action-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    form.append($(this).clone());
});
form.submit();
```

Now in your python (Python 2) `@action` method you can do the following :

```
@action
def action_custom(self, ids):
    _not_selected_ids = request.form.getlist('notrowid')
    print _not_selected_ids
```